# Special upvote privilege when accepting answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

Many users, if not most, register to Stack Overflow the day that they have a question important enough to ask. And once they have their answer, many will stop their interaction with Stack Overflow for a while, so may never reach the 15 reputation required to upvote the answer they accepted (or just forget about it).

I would suggest to allow every user to be able to upvote the accepted answer of their own question.

The rest of this question has been addressed by an answer, I do not support that anymore. I leave it for archive.

In fact, I am still uncertain why accepted answer don't get an upvote right away as I am sure there are thousands of case where the user just forget about upvoting, versus the cases on which an upvote could be harmful.

I do not suggest, but am cursious as to why accepted answer shouldn't get OP upvote right away.

Comment: Just like the main site: If you have a separate question, ask a separate question. Don't edit this one to favor the new question.

Comment: There is no new question, my only question remains and the second paragraph was open for clarification, which a user did.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not needed.  The acceptance checkmark already is more special than an upvote, because not only does it confer rep (more than an upvote), it also pins the answer to the top of the list.

Allowing new users to both accept and upvote would just allow sockpuppets to reach privileges more quickly, without any benefit.

It also would destroy the "Tenacious" and "Unsung Hero" medals.

Comment: I understand and upvoted you, yet don't fully agree. Even if not needed, *allowing* them to upvote is not useless. I get the problem with people cheating the system, but I guess there are other ways to prevent that. The fact that accepted answer is pinned is under discussion. The number of "reputation" lost because if this reason is probably consequent, so worth considering. The badges issue address my second question, thanks, even though badges are more for gamification while rep has a bigger actual impact, imho.

Comment: WRT "Tenacious" and "Unsung Hero" medals, low-rep users being able to upvote answers to their own questions does not automatically imply that they all would. There would still be a possibly large number of answers that would go without upvotes.

Comment: While acceptance does confer rep & pin the answer, leaderboards are based on upvotes. That aspect of the gamification of Q&A discourages help directed to low-rep users by leaderboard junkies, for questions that would have little appeal for higher-rep users.

Comment: Which leaderboard are you looking at that uses upvotes and not rep?

Comment: Any "Top Users" list, e.g. for [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers). The "Total score" is a count of upvotes, not total rep, and is the primary sort key for topusers. "Answers" is the secondary key. Javascript is a busy tag, and the total score is greater than the answer count for everyone appearing on the top users list. Compare that to a tag that attracts a large audience of new users - [Google Apps Script](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/topusers), and you'll find few cases where Total Score > Answers.

Comment: ...  Dig deeper, and there are some [1500 0-score accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+score%3A0+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes), out of about 4000 total accepted. The OPs are typically new users with low rep. Letting them upvote might increase the attention on the many unanswered questions.

Comment: + For defending the 'Tenacious' and 'Unsung Hero' medals as something to strive for.

Comment: I agree with @Mogstad on this.  It would encourage answering new users' questions which can be frustrating for a number of reasons... The OP's disappear, they change the question in their comments sometimes multiple times and for a lot of work you are rewarded with a single acceptance, experienced users who are more likely to upvote just don't go to those same questions as often, an unaccepted answer is quite unlikely to get any upvotes even if it is helpful and perhaps solves a significant part of the problem.  I think these problems of new users greatly outweighs the sockpuppet problem.

Comment: @Mark: When OPs disappear, the answerer is out the rep for the acceptance, and you propose that they miss out on more rep, which doesn't solve the perceived issue.  I disagree that the answer didn't get read by enough experts that it would have earned upvotes if it were high quality.  Questions going without views and answers to questions by new users going without upvotes seem related very weakly, if at all.  The problem with answering questions by new low-effort users is that when the Q is ambiguous, people coming by cannot tell if the answer is correct, because they can't tell if it relates